# Issue using Flash within bootstrap 3 modal

Tags: modal-dialog, flash

I'm using a "webcam" plugin within my application.  I had everything working good, until I decided to place the flash within a BS3 modal.  It seems BS3 modal is overlapping or disabling the Flash Settings for the "Camera & Microphone Access". Any suggestions? I would have posted a pic, but I don't have enough reputations yet, so here is a link, [Boostrap3 Modal w/ Flash Plugin](http://www.codebygregg.com/data/bs_modal.jpg)
Thank you!

I did forget to mention that everything works fine in Safari & Chrome, but not Firefox.

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709700/embed-tag-inside-bootstrap-modal-not-visible-in-firefox/23760007#23760007

Answer (score 1):

put `wmode="transparent"` in embed code part in your webcam.js

Comment: Excellent and easy solution, just want to add +10000 to this answer